# How do I create warp signs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am a staff member on a server, wanting to build a Capture the Flag section. I need to know how to make warp signs that let you teleport away, and only allow a certain amount of people to join.

Comment: Use one of the various plugins for Bukkit or Spigot. I recommend [CraftBook](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/craftbook/)

Comment: Command Block  or plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information, this is `/tp` not `/mvtp`, so it can only teleport you to somewhere in the same world

Fist off, run this command:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag: {Text1: "{text:\"Teleport\",color:\"green\",bold:true,clickEvent {action:\"run_command\",value:\"/teleport @p[r=4] <x> <y> <z>\"}}"},display:{Name: "Custom Sign"}}
```

This will teleport the closest player within 4 blocks to whatever you make the x y and z

I'm not sure about the limited player thing, but you could make a scoreboard ( `/scoreboard objectives add <name> Dummy` )

Add a `testfor` command that tests for everyone within a 100 block radius ( `/testfor @a[r=100]` )

And connect a comparator to it that has redstone attached to it which runs to a command block. (`/testfor` works with command blocks that makes it if there were 10 people within the 100 block area, it would put out 10 redstone charge).

This is as much as I can figure, Hope I helped!